# function execution order

Tags: f#

trying to understand In which order below f# code is executed and  how x%y is evaluated

Function converts a time duration given as a number of hours into a triple comprised of weeks, days and hours.

```
let hours2weeks (h : int) =
    let divAndRem x y = (x/y, x%y)
    let (w, h) = divAndRem h (7*24)
    let (d, h) = divAndRem h 24
    (w, d, h)


val hours2weeks : int -> int * int * int

> hours2weeks 1728
val it : int * int * int = (10, 2, 0)
>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. `%` is the [arithmetic modulus operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469493.aspx), as I'm sure you already know, so I'm not sure what you mean by "how it's evaluated".

Comment: code is reference from on line article, and i think  x%y is not required to calculate required result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trace the function execution by reducing the expression step-by-step (this is a very useful way to understanding execution that comes from Haskell and is called *computation by calculation*).

When you call a function:

```
hours2weeks 1728
```

F# evaluates the arguments and then starts evaluating the body:

```
let (w, h) = divAndRem 1728 (7*24)
let (d, h) = divAndRem 1728 24
(w, d, h)
```

It starts evaluating the argument of `let`. First it evaluates arguments of `divAndRem`

```
let (w, h) = divAndRem 1728 168
let (d, h) = divAndRem 1728 24
(w, d, h)
```

and then it calls the `divAndRem` function with the specified arguments:

```
let (w, h) = (1728/168, 1728%168)
let (d, h) = divAndRem h 24
(w, d, h)
```

The body of `divAndRem is evaluated and it gives a tuple with two numbers:

```
let (w, h) = (10, 48)
let (d, h) = divAndRem h 24
(w, d, h)
```

Then F# assigns the values to variables and continues:

```
let (d, h) = divAndRem 48 24
(10, d, h)
```

The second call to `divAndRem` is evaluated similarly:

```
let (d, h) = (2, 0)
(10, d, h)
```

So you get:

```
(10, 2, 0)
```

Now you can use this step-by-step evaluation to see that the `0` value in the result comes from the evaluation of `%` in the second `divAndRem` call and that the value `48` (result of the first `%` call) was needed to make the second `divAndRem` call.